# Tomcat8 kills my threads on shutdown

Tags: java, tomcat8

I created a webapplication that needs to do some cleanup on shutdown. This cleanup will take about a minute and its completely OK for it to do so.

When I deploy my webapp onto Tomcat 8 and then stop it, my ContextListener gets called and the cleanup begins. But it seems like Tomcat stops my thread the hard way and it won't complete anymore. At least on Tomcat 6 that wasn't an issue.

An ideas how to configure Tomcat 8 to stop from misbehaving?

**Partial Answer:**

I found out it has something to do with a performance optimization I did. I used `startStopThreads="2"` to start my applications in parallel, which works out well, but on shutdown this also seems to kill my threads.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a task which is to be performed on shutdown, I would add this as shutdown hook. Most likely Tomcat 8 is called System.exit() which is a normal thing to do and this kills all user threads but start shutdown hooks.

A better solution is to never leave the system in a state where you really need this. i.e. you cannot assume an application will die gracefully.

---

if you are waiting for client to disconnect, I suggest you add a shutting down phase.  During this phase you refuse new connections, move connections to another server or attempt to gracefully tell existing ones you are going away.  After a short period or time out, you then shut down.

Comment: I already did that! I implemented ServletContextListener and do the cleanup in the contextDestroyed() function. But somehow this function never comes to an end! I even catch ThreadDeatch but this does not seem to be thrown, so the stop() method doesn't seem to get run. And Tomcat 8 dumps all StackTraces on exit which seems to look like it detected something it doesn't like, but I don't see any documentation on it!

Comment: Btw. I do not really do cleanup. I wait for some clients to disconnect and to save their current changes. This worked before... sadly not now anmore.

Comment: @Daniel You *can't* wait for clients to disconnect. Tomcat will disconnect them all at its end, and you aren't supposed to do anything time-consuming in a shutdown hook. Revise your requirement.

Comment: @Daniel I have updated my answer.  I suspect the previous behaviour was unsafe and unsupportable which is why they removed it.

Comment: Maybe you are right... I should possibly enter the shutdown phase before sending Tomcat8 the stop signal. Would at least be a more reliable way to shutdown.